# How to fail a transaction in payment.create in paypal Express CheckOut?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to fail a transaction using the below code for paypal?

payment: function(data, actions) {

```
  return actions.payment.create({
  
transactions: [{
      amount: {
        total: '0.04',
        currency: 'USD'
      }


    }]
  });
  
},

// Execute the payment
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {   
    
  return actions.payment.execute(  

).then(function(result) {
  
  })
}
```

This jQuery written in client side. I get result.ack as success. How to get result.ack as Failure. So what request I have to pass in payment.create ()

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using an old version of the PayPal Checkout, called 'checkout.js'.  You should instead upgrade to the latest JS SDK; here is a demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

But regardless, there is no way to make the create call fail on a client-side only integration other than simply passing a bad value to it.

---

[Negative testing for REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/sandbox/nt-rest/) is available for server-based integration patterns ([documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls)). For the case of a JS create action, the server would then fail to return a valid id string. This results in a JS console error and halts further execution. The `onError` function would also be triggered, if one is defined. Effectively this is the same as what happens in the above mentioned case (passing a bad value to the create function)